# Connect with SSL and phpmyadmin to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ssl

I'm trying to connect to my SQL database but the connection between phpmyadmin and the database should be encrypted with SSL. I running the database on docker.
Phpadmin can connect to the database sucessfully, but my next goal is now SSL. But I dont understand the documentation of phpmyadmin right. I need to set this variables in the `config.user.inc.php` file:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = <bool>;
$cfg['ForceSSL'] = <bool>;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_key'] = <string>;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_cert'] = <string>;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_ca'] = <string>;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_ca_path'] = <string>;
```

That is now the problem, from where can I get the `*.pem` and `*.ca` files? Which must be generated or just copied?

It looks currently like this:

[image: Screenshot]

What I did:

1. I saw in the mysql volume four files (can I use this files, but how?):

- private_key.pem
- oublic_key.pem
- server-cert.pem
- server-key.pem

Answer (score 0):

you need to generate those files on your own.
Maybe you can use a manual like the following one (mysql should be the same)

[Configure secure connection](https://www.osradar.com/configure-mariadb-with-ssl-to-secure-connections/)

After this you have to modify your Dockerfile to copy the generated files into the container. Also do not forget to create a config file to make use of this.

Best,
Frank